# Invalid byte sequence in conversion input - Shell

Tags: bash, shell, character-encoding

I'm having problems with some Chinese characters. 
The error message is:

```
 Unable to parse command line: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input
```

How do you usually solve this problem in shell.
Apparently are just a few strange characters.

```
 echo "资料来源：新京报、京华时报、" | cut -c 1-40
```

output

```
资料来源：新京报、京华时报�
```

Comment: Have you tried using a UTF-8-aware `cut(1)`?
`$ echo "资料来源：新京报、京华时报、" | cut -c 1-40`
`资料来源：新京报、京华时报、`

Comment: There is a bug in coreutils cut.  Either use cut -b or try patching.  See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/coreutils-that-are-utf-aware

Comment: Thanks, it's a bug, but I managed to work replacing cut by awk.